# how to contain error situation in pytest fixture (scope = "module")

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pycharm, pytest

I recently started coding using pytest fixtures and have setup function which bring up and configures various nodes in the network.

For writing automation test cases, creating setup is one time activity and is error prone as well. As this is one time hence, scope is set to "module" or "session"

While implementing frixtures, as per pytest documenation / recommendation, I implemented it somewhat like this:

```
class xxx:

    @pytest.fixture(scop = "module", autouse=True)
    def setup(self, request):
        -----lines of code ---------
        def teardown():
            ------cod for tear down --------
        request.addfinalizer(teardown)
```

How to handle the situation when an error occurs in setup fixture, ideally it should invoke teardown and execution is stopped at that point i.e. test cases should not get executed further.

Thanks for you reply.

Comment: raise an exception?

Comment: any better choice than un-handled exception? Or may be then I have to Yield it rather than addfinallizer and gracefully exit via except. Seems likely !!

Comment: Fixtures should not have any errors anyway - they are no tests. if you encounter any errors in a fixture, you should fix them and not try to proceed with half-baked tests.